# Crontab for shell not working

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, cron, cron-task, cronexpression

I have a program named all.sh in the directory home/hmm

```
52 08 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/hmm/all.sh
```

It doesn't run. I know where is something wrong in the `/usr/bin/sh`. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path to the sh executable is wrong.  In your interactive shell type: "which sh" to get the actual location and use that in your crontab entry. (It's probably /bin/sh)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it manually? Do you see any error messages when you run it in terminal?
Please also check `/usr/bin/sh -n /home/hmm/all.sh` to check bash script syntax.

Comment: I just checked there is no directory such as usr/bin/sh. then what to do

Comment: Are you working chroot environment? Also, please try to change `/usr/bin/sh` to `/usr/bin/env bash`